# 403 error while deleting the pipeline in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have generated personal access token and I have Maintainer Access for specific repository in gitlab.I have used below API to delete the pipeline

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <mytoken>" --request "DELETE" https://gitlab.test.com/api/v4/projects/8/pipelines/5461
```

I'm getting 403 error. How to fix this issue

Comment: What scope did you give the access token when you created it? You can view them here using your GItlab server domain: hxxps://your-gitlab-server.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens

Comment: same problem  with "api" scope